# Unable to add matrices to tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, tuples

New to python and numpy, searched and tried all possible solution not getting results
I have a function that returns 2 matrices. I want to create an array or matrices that saves each of the matrices being returned by my function. I've done so many different versions, this was the closest. I'm used to java and not python. If I do the following: `centroidsm[0]` and `clustersm[0]`, I cannot get each individual array.

This is my code:

```
centroidsm = []
centroidsm.append([])
clustersm = []
clustersm.append([])
for k in range(2,20):
    centroids, clusters = kMeans(train, k)
    centroidsm[k].append(centroids)
    clustersm[k].append(clusters)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know why you're appending an empty array to `centroidsm`. You should do away with those lines.

Second, if centroidsm is supposed to be an array of centroid matrices, you simply need to call `centroidism.append(centroids)` inside you for loop (`centroidsm[k].append` attempts to append to an array at index k - an array that doesn't exist).

```
centroidsm = []
clustersm = []
for k in range(2,20):
    centroids, clusters = kMeans(train, k)
    centroidsm.append(centroids)
    clustersm.append(clusters)
```

Comment: I keep getting index out of error

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-282-c11b4d4a9375> in <module>()
      2 for j in range(2,20):
      3     centroids, clusters = kMeans(train, j)
----> 4     centroidsm[j].append(centroids)
      5     clustersm[j].append(clusters)

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Reason why I wanted k in there was because I want to be able to access each centroids matrix individually. If i just do centroidsm.append(centroids), i can only call all the arrays of centroids not specific ones

Comment: You can access specific matrices with `centroidism[k]` once you have built the array.

Comment: Of course you get IndexError: Your `centroidsm` list has length 1 when the for loop starts, and then you try to access its third element (index=2).

Comment: perfect! it wasnt workign before but your advice worked.. Thank you! before i could only access centroidm[0] and it would have all of htem in there. Thank you!!! I just have to wrap my head around python more. I am just so use to java

Comment: You will never want to touch Java again ;), and don't forget to accept the answer to give @slider some cred!